# Is there any way to circumference of a circle with radius but without pi?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, circles, pi, experimental-mathematics

Please let me know if anybody knows how to calculate the circumference of a circle with radius but without pi?

Comment: The circumference of a circle with radius one *is* $2 \pi$, what do you mean by “calculating it without pi”? – If this is meant as a serious question then you need to clarify it.

Comment: i am just curious to know that if  pi  was not found there would not have been any other method to calculate circumferences of a circle? only with pi it is possible?

Comment: Since there is no nice form solution for the circumference or area of a circle one simply defines $\pi$, so we can work with a nice value.

Comment: As pi’s  decimal expansion never ends  how can we get an end result of the circumference of the circle using pi

Comment: Food for thought: The diagonal of a unit square is $\sqrt 2$, also a never ending, never repeating decimal.

Comment: There are many ways to denote a number. Decimals is only one way. And sure, not all numbers can be accurately described using decimals and finite space.  That doesn't mean they can't be accurately described or that they should somehow be avoided.

Comment: You can use approximate circumference calculation using formula  (based on well known $\pi$ approximation) $$C \approx \dfrac{710}{113} R,$$
which provides good enough precision: if $R=1000$km, then the error in circumference calculation will be not greater than $1$mm :)

Comment: Thanks. 710/113 is nothing but  6.28 (2pi) . How 710/113 is derived, any idea?

Comment: Links for $355/113$ approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil%C3%BC , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zu_Chongzhi .

Comment: $710/113 \ne 6.28 \ne 2\pi$.

Comment: Ooops, typo in previous comment: error $< 1$mm for $R=1$km.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the information

Comment: You should observe that the question "what does one mean by a circumference of a circle" arises first and then later one defines the symbol $\pi$ as the circumference of a circle with unit diameter. So indeed the circumference is found out without $\pi$.

Comment: Probably it is time for you to read some analysis textbooks which deal with areas of plane figures and length of plane curves in rigorous manner.

Answer (score 2):

It is a secret of euclidean geometry (not valid, e.g.,  in spherical geometry) that all figures can be linearly scaled by arbitrary real factors $\lambda>0$, whereby the lengths of all segments and curves are multiplied by $\lambda$ and the areas of nice domains are multiplied by $\lambda^2$. From this it follows that for circles there has to be a formula
$${\rm circumference}=C\cdot {\rm diameter}\ ,$$
whereby $C$ is a "world constant". This is known to humanity since thousands of years. Later the constant of value slightly larger than $3$ has been denoted by $\pi$, and only in the last years of the $19^{\rm th}$ century it has been proven that this $\pi$ is very irrational, and not even expressible in terms of square roots or similar. But $\pi$ is an ordinary real number and has its "infinite precision" like every such number, e.g. $7$.

Comment: Sir I have calculated  the circumference using a simple formula using a fixed whole number and a decimal multiplied by the  radius. I get the result 99%  accuracy with the result calculated using  pi. is that of any use.